# how to implement text search functionality for report viewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

This is my report page, on which my report viewer is working. I want to search data by text box that I designed on top of my report viewer.

```
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="auto-style1">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </asp:ScriptManager>
      <table class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style4" Text="Patient Report"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="137px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="auto-style3">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="218px" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="1010px">
              <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
                <DataSources>
                  <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                </DataSources>
              </LocalReport>
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="MedImage.DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It might work for you:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/452077/how-to-pass-Csharp-form-textbox-value-to-textbox-i